# Grunt build doesn't combine styles inside of build:css(.tmp)

Tags: javascript, html, gruntjs, frontend, yeoman

I use Yeoman angular generator and Grunt for front-end. Inside of my build:css(.tmp)section in index.html, i have added several css files but, just first and sass files generated in main.css files in build.

```
<!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/components-scss.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/register.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/custom.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

componets-scss.css contain bootstrap sass file loading and font awesome. another styles is normal style. In Grunt Build just first file (componets-scss.css) combined and minified bootstrap and font awesome.

Every thing is working as well in Grunt serve mod.

Answer (score 0):

I change to this one and now it's work.

```
<!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/components-scss.css">
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/register.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/custom.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```